# Dynamic class loading as one of the reason of permgen?

Tags: java, jvm

On different sites , Dynamic class loading is given  as one of the reason of permgen problem.

As per my understanding , Dynamic class loading is loading the class as and when it is required.Alonwith that if Class A is loaded and it is referring another class B , it will also be loaded along with that. This is Dynamic class loading. **Right?**  If yes, this is essential and inbuilt feature of JVM. **What we can do about it?**

Or my understanding is wrong here. when we say Dynamic class loading , are we reffering to custom class loaders here?

My last question related to above is, Class is loaded once by customer loader. So when we do hotdeployment on application server, **how appserver loads the new version of class. Does it use different class loader here?**

Comment: Check this out: http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, dynamic class loading refers to loading classes during runtime that are unknown at compile time, e.g., via `Class.forName`, or reflection ([1](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html), [2](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Reflection/Dynamic_Class_Loading)).

Comment: Hi dave , but all the classes are loaded at run time. Right? As per my understanding Class.forName is usefule when you dont know the name of class at compilation time.But still all the  classes are loaded at run time.

Comment: Dynamic class loading refers to loading classes at runtime *that are **unknown** at compile time*.